# Base 64 encoding an image file in Groovy using Apache Commons

Tags: java, groovy, encoding, base64, apache-commons-codec

I am trying to encode an image file to a Base64 String using the directions on this [site](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-image-string). The only difference is I have a groovy script (instead of Java), my entire script is just....

```
  @Grapes(
    @Grab(group='commons-io', module='commons-io', version='2.6')
  )

 import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
 import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64


  byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File('/Users/me/Test.jpeg'));
  String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
```

When I run this I get the below exception and can't figure out why...

```
 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
 No signature of method: static org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.getEncoder() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
 Possible solutions: encode([B), encode(java.lang.Object)
```

Comment: The Base64 class doesn't have a getEncoder() method, but it does have a bunch of methods to encode: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: in groovy it's possible to do the same without external libraries: `new File('/Users/me/Test.jpeg').getBytes().encodeBase64()`

Answer (score 0):

You're importing `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`.

With `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent)` you're calling `java.util.Base64`, which has methods other than `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`.

Since `java.util.*` is one of Groovy's default imports your code should work when you remove `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`.